# Access Violation when debbuging windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8.1

recently I encountered a problem. Every time when I make some changes in page after I debug it on device when going to said page the app minimizes (crashes) and after about 30-50 seconds in output window I get

> The program 'XXX' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

But when I uninstall and then debug again It works. I already tied reseting phone. Is it something with my debbuger or more likely with my code?

Edit:
Right now sometimes it occurs and sometime it doesnt ... I'll need to inspect code more. Is there a way to obtain more debug info with Access violation information?

Comment: You can actually see the dump of debug on the test device, Follow this [link](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2015/02/19/windows-phone-8-1-debugging-getting-a-crash-dump-file-from-a-device.aspx). If it helped you, Let me know to post as answer to help others.

Comment: Yes that link was something that I have been looking for for quite some time, there was little information and still info that I tried to access some data from wrong thread was enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post as answer so others can see it easily.

You can see the dump of debug on the test device, Follow this
[link](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2015/02/19/windows-phone-8-1-debugging-getting-a-crash-dump-file-from-a-device.aspx).

Basically the link explains how to turn on "Save Information option" from Feedback application inside Settings of your device. After that when you debug the app, you will find dump file of your application inside,Phone -> Documents ->Debug.

Answer (score 1):

Please post a sample of your code. I had similar problems when I tried using {unsafe code} and included pointers. They are extremely useful, but often lead you to memory problems (reading from a NULL pointer or something like that), so check if that's your problem.

Good luck

Comment: In my case unsafe was navigation, I had to navigate inside dispatcher. It seems like it was the reason but I am going to make more tests

Comment: keep me posted on anything you might need!